# Прикрутить поля значений к созданной странице в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

Помогите разобраться. Создаю новую страницу в админ-меню. В ней подстраницу. Хочу туда вставить поле, значение которого сохраняется и его можно вывести в нужном месте в коде. Как это сделать, подскажите

```html
function sandbox_create_menu_page() {

    add_menu_page(
        'Секции главной',
        'Секции главной',
        'administrator',
        'sandbox',
        'sandbox_menu_page_display',
        'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
        21
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'sandbox',
        'О нас',
        'О нас',
        'administrator',
        'sandbox_options',
        'sandbox_options_display'
    );

    // Пытаюсь вывести поле, но оно не выводится
    add_settings_field(
        'test',
        'title',
        'test_callback',
        'sandbox',
        '',
        ''
    );


} 

// Как должно выглядеть поле значений
function test_callback($args) {

$html = '<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="1" ' . checked(1, get_option('show_header'), false) . '/>';

$html .= '<label for="test"> ' . $args[0] . '</label>';

echo $html;

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'sandbox_create_menu_page');

// Страница главная, можно не смотреть
function sandbox_menu_page_display() {

    // Создание тега заголовка в стандартном контейнере «wrap»
    $html = '<div class="wrap">';
    $html .= '<h4>Выбирайте секцию</h4>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    // Посылаем разметку на вывод в браузер
    echo $html;

}

function sandbox_options_display() { ?>


    <!-- Создаем заголовок в стандартном контейнере «wrap» -->
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>О нас</h2>
        <!-- Делаем вызов функции WordPress для вывода ошибок, возникающих при сохранении настроек. -->
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <!-- Создаем форму, которая будет использоваться для вывода наших опций -->
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'general' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'general' ); ?>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- Конец контейнера «wrap» -->
    <?php
}
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью плагина ACF - очень всё просто и понятно
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
Есть хороший и форум у них, и много документации.